# User input to query data from SQL table using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have created a very simple table using SQL, like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE chain
    (column1     CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
    column2      CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
    column3      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    column4      SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (column1)
);
```

I want any future user to be able to query data from this table automatically:

```
Print("""Select the column number for your search""")
user_search = input("Write your column number:")
```

Now, I don't know how to go on... is there a way of using the user's input to get info from the table using a python script?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have the table, I have the fake data and the idea... but not sure what I need to do, or even where I could get the information to start writing something